# Javascript with Firefox innerText issue

Tags: javascript, firefox

```
function OpenWindow(anchor) {
        var toUsername = anchor.innerText;
        window.open("ChatWindow.aspx?username=" + toUsername,'_blank', "width=340,height=200");       
    }
```

this function opens up a page with parameter as undefined in firefox where as in google chrome  I get proper value.

Firefox url:
http://localhost:9452/ChatWindow.aspx?username=undefined

What is the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While `innerText` is non-standard, it significantly differs from `textContent`, because first one is doing *pretty printing* (for example, `<br/>` are converted to new lines), while second one - is not.

So, while common wisdom is to use:

```
var toUsername = anchor.innerText || anchor.textContent;
```

or some kind of wrapper, it can probably be smarter to just use jQuery's `.text` or its analog from other library you are using.

Answer (score 2):

try to change `anchor.innerText` with:

```
anchor.textContent
```

this hopefully works in all browsers.

also see here: ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

**P.S.** I really reccomend using JQuery to avoid these kind of issues and to be sure to always write fully cross-browser javascript.

Comment: Just a little note: `textContent` does not work in IE8.

Comment: yes exactly, that's why I suggested to use JQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

`innerText` is a Microsoft invention whereas `textContent` is a W3C standard.

```
function OpenWindow(anchor) {
    var toUsername = anchor.textContent || anchor.innerText || '';
    window.open("ChatWindow.aspx?username=" + toUsername,'_blank', "width=340,height=200");       
}
```

This should work. MooTools or some other JavaScript framework should be able to help with cross-browser inconsistencies.

Comment: MooTools! good one! :)

Answer (score 1):

use textContent for innerText.
example

```
<script>
function change()
{
   document.getElementById("label").textContent="Hello";
}
</script>
```

**it will work on ff. and chrome too. but not work on IE.**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem because Firefox does not support the innerText property, instead, it supports the textContent property. so check for the browser’s feature support to use the correct property accordingly.

```
if(document.all){
 document.getElementById('element').innerText = "myText";
} else{
document.getElementById('element').textContent = "myText";
}
```

or it's better to use Jquery to resolve cross browser issues.
Usage:

```
$('element').text("myText");
```