# innerText not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, innertext

This is my code:

```
<div id="code">My program<br />It is here!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var program=document.getElementById('code');
ShowLMCButton(program.innerText);
</script>
```

It works in IE but in firefox, innerText does not work. How can I use this in firefox? I have tried .text() but it doesn't want to work!
I need the text to be in the form "My program\n It is here!"

What this is, is to copy a VB script from a site and paste it straight into a program and it must include all the new lines etc.

Comment: I think this question is already on the site.
Will [this][1] help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461598/javascript-with-firefox-innertext-issue

Comment: That edit should have been a different question!

Answer (score 2):

You used the tag [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), so I assume that you use jQuery. Hence you have to refer to the **jQuery** object and not the `HTMLObject`.

```
<div id="code">My program<br />It is here!</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var program = $('#code');
    ShowLMCButton(program.text());
</script>
```

Comment: I need it to do "pretty printing", which this does not

Comment: @JoshLukeBlease "Pretty printing" - can you clarify?

Answer (score 2):

you could check for the browser’s feature support to use the correct property accordingly.

```
var program=document.getElementById('code');
if(document.all){
     ShowLMCButton(program.innerText);
} else{
     ShowLMCButton(program.textContent);
}
```

document.all will basically determines if the browser is IE (Microsoft extension to the W3C-standard)

Comment: will textContent work in all browsers other than IE?

Comment: Pretty much yeah. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 2):

innerText is not supported by FireFox as you say.
I found innerHTML to be a good solution to this problem.

From:
document.getElementById('<%= LblMapLat.ClientID %>').innerText 
To:
document.getElementById('<%= LblMapLat.ClientID %>').innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

innerText doesn't work in firefox . if you can , use innerHTML . and if can't , you can use textContent . you should do this , to work with firefox and IE simultaneous :

```
ShowLMCButton(program.innerText||program.textContent);
```

Comment: this will give appended result chrome where both the properties will work..

Comment: @logan when you use ' || ' if first property ( or anything else ) is available , use that , and if it isn't , use second property ; therefore that hasn't any problem . i tested a code here: [link](http://notepad.cc/ciadiesca97) ;)

Comment: Why did you give me down vote?

Comment: you can't ask people who downvoted as it is unknown..

Comment: I didn't ask who, I asked why; If there is any problem here, it's better me to know that. I'm using this approach usually.

Answer (score 0):

Use, `textContent` which will work in Firefox and IE as well..