# Mozilla Firefox not getting value innerText

Tags: javascript, asp.net, firefox, cross-browser

This is my JavaScript code:

```js
function selectRow(objTR) {
    for (i = 0; i < ddlModalityList.options.length; i++) {
        if (ddlModalityList.options[i].text == objTR.cells[1].innerText.trim()) break;
    }

    ddlModalityList.options[i].selected = true;
    txtSSAETitle.value = objTR.cells[2].innerText.trim();
    txtSSName.value = objTR.cells[3].innerText.trim();
}
```

This is repeater code. On row click I am passing id of tr and displaying respective td value in respective dropdownlist and textboxes. This code works fine in IE but fails in Mozilla Firefox.

```html
<tr onclick="selectRow(this);">   
    <td class="csstablelisttd" style="display: none;" >
        <%#Eval("Acq_Modality_ID")%>
    </td>                     
    <td class="csstablelisttd" >                            
        <asp:Label ID="lblModality" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Modality")%>'></asp:Label>
    </td>

    <td class="csstablelisttd">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSchdledStAETitle" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Scheduled_Station_AE_Title")%>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td class="csstablelisttd">
        <asp:Label ID="lblSchdleStationAEName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SCHEDULED_STATION_NAME")%>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please start putting some effort into formulating your questions. Code is **not** the question, explain the problem in words **first**. Only put the **relevant** code into your question - e.g. if it is a client-side problem then ASP code is absolutely irrelevant, post the generated HTML code if necessary (here it isn't). And indent your code properly so that people can read it!

Answer (score 7):

Firefox does not support `innerText`. You can use `textContent` instead. However, older IE does not support `textContent`, so you'll need to use one and fall back to the other.

```
function getInnerText(el) {
    return el.textContent || el.innerText;
}
```

Note that they're [not identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/96100), but for your purposes it will be fine.

Comment: txtSSAETitle.value = objTR.cells[2].textContent.trim();       Error: 'cells.2.textContent' is null or not an object//In IE  //AND in mozilla also not working

Comment: @harsh: In that case, that cell does not exist. `textContent` is definitely implemented in Firefox.

Comment: what exactly i have pass to function because i am getting text from td (cell of tr)and showing in respective textbox and ddl

Comment: @harsh: `getInnerText(objTR.cells[2])`, although obviously you need to be sure the cell exists.

Comment: txtSSAETitle.value= getInnerText(objTR.cells[2]);
            function getInnerText(el) {
                return el.textContent || el.innerText;
            }//this works in IE but not in firefox

Comment: @harsh: It does work in Firefox. Check that your table cell exists before calling the function. The problem may be in the `cells` collection: there could be (although I don't know) a difference in browser handling of hidden table cells.

Comment: Tim:cell is exist and works in IE properly..but in firefox failure

Answer (score 2):

Use **innerHTML** instead of innerText. InnerText will not work in FF. innerHTML will work on both of them.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1228392/2210082.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Firefox does not support innerText.. `you should use jquery` so that you dont need to care about the difference in browers implementation
so using jquery your code would be

```
function selectRow(objTR) {
    for (i = 0; i < ddlModalityList.options.length; i++) {
        if (ddlModalityList.options[i].text == $(objTR).children('td').eq(1).html().trim()) break;
    }

    ddlModalityList.options[i].selected = true;
    txtSSAETitle.value = $(objTR).children('td label').eq(2).html().trim();
    txtSSName.value = $(objTR).children('td label').eq(3).html().trim();
}
```

im leaving the `ddlModalityList` as it is because i dont know what it is.

Comment: How shold i use jquery for this purpose did u pls explain with some code

Comment: txtSSAETitle.value=$(objTR).children('tr').eq(2).html() //i have use code but not working in both iE and firefox

Comment: i apologize i wrote "tr" instead of "td".. i have edited my code again.. plz go thru it and still if u face any prob use jsfiddle. and ill edit teh code there

Comment: what error are you encountering?

Comment: The nearest jQuery equivalent to `innerText` is `text()`, not `html()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectRow(objTR) {
    for (i = 0; i < ddlModalityList.options.length; i++) {
        if (ddlModalityList.options[i].text == $(objTR).children('td').eq(1).html().trim()) break;
    }

    ddlModalityList.options[i].selected = true;
    txtSSAETitle.value = $(objTR).children('td label').eq(2).html().trim();
    txtSSName.value = $(objTR).children('td label').eq(3).html().trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('InputText').innerHTML.replace(/<.+?>/gim,''));