# How do I input specific tags by calculating the text length which user input in textarea?

Tags: javascript, string, tags, dhtml

I'm using personally customed wysiwyg dhtml editor.
The editor's only usable on desktop.
But I want it to be shown on both Desktop and Mobile.
(And it needs specific class of  tag and  tag.)
And that got me thingking... Desktop(mostly laptops) and Mobile devices are not the same.
they have different pixels~ If i'm using just text data this would not be a problem.
But I'm using specific  &  tags
(their width and height must be defined in CSS with pixels)
Basically I need to find the way to put two different type of tags(one for Desktop,one for Mobile)
from One incoming input(which user input to dhtml editor textarea) by calculating text input.

```
ex>
.my_div
{
width: 450px;
height: 550px; 

}
.my_div .my_span
{
width: 350px;
height: 530px;


Ex1> <div class="my_div"><span class"my_span">It's like when the text user input here is more than
height of 530px....close this one and... </span></div>
<div class="my_div"><span class"my_span">...and in put new div and span tags automatically, reapeatedly until i press "End" button then close it with </span></div>
```

And when Ex1> is hadeled... I want to send two different text Data to mysql DB.
One for Desktop One for Mobile. So Basically I need to of Ex1> one with height of 530px(for desktop)
and one with 350px(for mobile)

I'd love to take the answer with whole code but, just keyword! or method or basically anything related with that monster thing.... :(
I've been up 3 day and night bbecause of this! my head is about to explode...
and every search result i've got ...just showing how to 'remove' tags or how to input 
 tag
automatically Please help me~ Thank you for your time~

Comment: You should be using CSS to differentiate the mobile experience, not HTML tags.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need <div<span> for specific customed jquery-ui...

Answer (score 0):

- Height is equal to font size * number of lines
- Number of lines is equal to text length / width of textarea
- Text length is equal to characters + whitespace for monospace fonts, not for others
- Characters + whitespace is returned by [textContent/innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) property after [trimming](http://wonko.com/post/how_not_to_write_a_javascript_trim_function)

Answer (score 0):

You may try JavaScript + jQuery to sniff if the device is mobile and load the relevant css. Try Detect Mobile Browsers JavaScript plugin.