# Firefox undefined value when using jquery to read cell elements

Tags: firefox, undefined, tablerow

I have a table which is populated dynamically (using update panel), and then when a user clicks a chosen row, all the data is written to a label. Works fine in IE and chrome, but firefox says undefined. Simple table with 5 columns. I bind dynamically to the table with the following: (please excuse the code bloat)

```
    $('#tblResults').delegate(".aRow", "click", function () {
            var thatID = this.id;
            if (thatID != "0") {
                var wordz = "";
                var specialID = document.getElementById("hiddenChosenContact");
                var targetContact = document.getElementById("theContactLabel");

                for (var i = 1; i <= this.cells.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (i == this.cells.length - 1)
                        wordz = wordz + this.cells[i].innerText;
                    else
                        wordz = wordz + this.cells[i].innerText + " - ";
                }

                targetContact.innerHTML = wordz;
                specialID.value = thatID;
            }
            else {

            }
     });
```

The row is given an id and classname 'aRow' on load.
I tried using full jquery only, $(this), but to be honest i am not sure on the syntax for table manipulation.

**edit. Sorry, meant to say that the undefined value is contained within this.cells[i].innerText

**HTML Edit

```
<table class="cvTableG" id="tblResults" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" style="clear:left; width:100%; font-size:10px;">
            <thead>
              <tr class="aRow" id="1"><th width="14px;">&nbsp;</th>
                <th align="left" width="85px">Name</th>
                <th align="left" width="90px">Surname</th>
                <th align="left">Department</th>
                <th align="left">Customer</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="aRow" id="2">
                <td style="padding:0;"><input type="radio" name="myRadio" /></td>
                <td>Marty</td>
                <td>Elliott</td>
                <td>Development Place</td>
                <td>Rosebank</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="aRow" id="3">
              <td style="padding:0;"><input type="radio" name="myRadio" /></td>
                <td>Sarah</td>
                <td>Lee</td>
                <td>Dev Place</td>
                <td>JHB</td>
              </tr>
               <tr class="aRow" id="4">
               <td style="padding:0;"><input type="radio" name="myRadio" /></td>
                <td>Marty</td>
                <td>Elliott</td>
                <td>Halfway House</td>
                <td>Durban</td>
              </tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Please share the html fragment with the table.

Comment: Edit Above. Apologies ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

I once had a problem with Jquery selectors that occur only in firefox. If i remember correctly the solution was to add name property with the same value as in id. So in your case it would be:

```
<table class="cvTableG" id="tblResults" name="tblResults">
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

I have found the tutorial and you may want to try something like this:

---

For example, the following .delegate() code:

```
$("table").delegate("td", "click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

is equivalent to the following code written using .on():

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("chosen");
});
```

Maybe it will work this way?

Comment: Hey mnmnc, tried, not working ;( - Gonna keep it in mind though for next project;

Comment: Hey Mnmnc. Tried that, still did not work. It seems it is happy getting to the function, but not happy finding the value within the cell. With great effort I got a dom inspector, and saw that firefox labels it cell attribute for inner values as "innerHTML". thus the innerText above would not work. innerHTML seems fine also on other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't implement the non-standard `innerText` property.  Did you perhaps want `textContent`, which *is* standardized?