# How do I pull the value from a selection of a HTML drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I display the selected option name in the div above it? If user has blue selected I want blue to show above.

```
<div id='text"> selection goes here</div>
<select id="dropdownselect">
<option> Red </option>
<option> White </option>
<option> Blue </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following to get the text of the selected option:

```
var select = document.getElementById("dropdownselect");
var selectedText = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
```

Then, to add the value to the `div` with id `text`, use:

```
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = selectedText;
```

If you want to reflect the selected value every time the option has changed, you need to attach the `onchange` event to the `select`, which, combined with the above code results in the following:

```
var select = document.getElementById("dropdownselect");
select.onchange = function () {
  var selectedText = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = selectedText;
};​
```

Here's a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BunMV/)**.

Comment: Well I found the answer to my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1359469/1331430

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Thanks, I've switched to `innerHTML` since in this case the end result is the same.

Comment: I'm getting the following "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null "

Comment: @SamDanger Be sure that you've typed `dropdownselect` right, in the line above `onchange` event binding.

Comment: Double checked in Rafael. It matches.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `onchange` `javascript` event:

```
<div id="text"> selection goes here</div>
<select id="dropdownselect" onchange="document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;">
    <option> Red </option>
    <option> White </option>
    <option> Blue </option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Whilst *correct*, it's a common practice to don't use inline event handlers, in order to have a clear separation between behaviour/javascript and presentation/markup.

Comment: NO! Not me, I *never* *ever* casted a downvote here on StackOverflow. Check my profile.

Comment: Hmm.. not working for me:
`<div id="text"></div>
<select id="dropdownselect" onchange="document.getElementById(" text').innerhtml="this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;'" name="options[16]">
<option value="43">Blue</option>
<option value="44">Green</option>
<option value="45">Pink</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a javascript framework to make it much easier. I personally use jQuery, in which case the javascript to get the value is:

```
$("#dropdownselect").val()
```

And you can change it automatically with:

```
<select id="dropdownselect" onChange="$('#text').text($(this).val());">
```

Similar functions are available with MooTools, or other frameworks I haven't used before.

jQuery can be made available with:

```
<script src="jquery.js"><!-- assuming you have a jquery file at this location -->
```

Comment: If the option's value attribute is not present then it will return the text

Comment: Thanks Ronalchn. I'm using Jquery, but I im still getting a blank div. here is my code: 
`<div id="text"></div>
<select id="dropdownselect" onchange="$(" #text').text($(this).val());'="" style="display:block; clear:both; margin-bottom:10px;" name="options[16]"><option value="43">Blue</option><option value="44">Green</option><option value="45">Pink</option></select>`

Comment: maybe try `onChange="$('#text').text($('#dropdownselect option:selected').text());"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById("dropdownselect"),
    textDiv = document.getElementById("text");
textDiv.innerText = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].text;
```

But i'd recommend using jQuery too.