# Jquery equivalent/ Browser compatibility for e.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[i].innerText;

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am using the following snippet for updating some textbox value from a table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>ProjectName</td>
    <td>Block</td>
    <td>.WorkProgressMilestone</td>
    <td>Completion</td>
    <td>
       <span class="sep">
       <img height="15px" width="20px" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/Edit.png")" />
       </span>
       <a href="#" onclick="EditWorkDetails(this);" style="text-decoration: none">Edit</a>
       <input id="WorkProgressEditID" name="WorkProgressEditID" type="hidden" value="@v.WorkProgressID" />
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>..</tr>
 </table>


function EditWorkDetails(e) {
document.getElementById("txtCompletion").value = e.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[3].innerText;
}
```

It works fine for me in IE, but not working in other browsers(Chrome). A notable thing is that the table 'td's and 'tr's don't have Id property to distinguish each other. So I can't use jquery over here. What is the alternative I can follow to make it work in all browsers.

Comment: `So I can't use jquery`? Do you want to use jQuery or not?

Comment: It could use jQuery. But could you post the html code too, and the function too, maybe there is an better way.

Comment: `innerText` is the IE-only code, in other browsers it is `textContent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("txtCompletion").value = $(this).parent().parent().children()[3].html();
```

or

```
$("txtCompletion").val($(this).parent().parent().children()[3].html());
```

Comment: Thanks Finally This worked for me $("#txtCompletion").val($(e).parent().parent().children()[3].innerHTML);

Answer (score 1):

Yyou have two problems:

1. `innerText` is not universally supported.
2. All browsers except IE < 9 (and IE 9 in compatibility modes) include whitespace text nodes in `childNodes`. IE does not, so `tr.childNodes[3]` is going to refer to different nodes if you have whitespace between your `<td>` elements.

The fixes I'd recommend:

1. Use `element.textContent || elem.innerText`. This is [not perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/96100) but will work fine in most cases.
2. It looks like you're trying to get the text content of a table cell. If so, you can use the `cells` property of the table, which is universally supported back to IE 4.

Example code with both fixes:

```
var td = e.parentNode.parentNode.cells[3];
var tdText = td.textContent || td.innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

innerText is not supported in all browsers, you might try using jquery 
or

use .textContent and .innerText based on browser version