# Changing td text without affecting two hidden field inside the td

Tags: jquery, json

I have a situation where I have a `HTML table`.
It has some `td`.
Every td has some text and two `hidden field`.

I have a `json source` for my table td text. 
I want to change the text of the all the td of the table without changing the two hidden field.
**Earlier I was using jTemplate and json for the same.**
 But I was bringing the hidden field values in the Jason for every td which was not different from the original value. 
So I decided to change my approach to bring only the text which need to be replace.
 I know how to change the text of the td in jQuery using `text()` and `html()` method.
But will it change the text without affecting the controls (hidden field) inside td?

---edit ---
One of my td is like

```
 <table id='demoTable'>
 <tr>
 <td>8: Tap on APN and Enter <B>www</B>.
     <INPUT id=h150000000000000109743 class=hid value="test value" type=hidden>
     <INPUT id=h250000000000000109743 class=hid1 value="26,222,98,10,50000000000000109744,T,~25,221,99,10,,T,www" type="hidden">
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

And my jquery is like this

```
 function changeText() {
        $("#demoTable td").each(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $(this).children.length; i++) {
                alert($(this).children(i).val());
            }
            //                alert($(this).html());
            //                $(this).text("hello");
            //alert($(this).html());
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this

get your `table td` and change the first child content like this if you have first child as text content

```
var text_to_chang = document.getElementById("td").childNodes[0];
text_to_change.nodeValue = 'new text';
```

Comment: do everything inside create a childNodes. If yes then will I have three childNodes in my td?

Comment: place an alert and test for childnodes like alert(td.childNodes.length) and tell me how many childNodes you have

Comment: what about the white spaces in my text of td will it create a childNode? Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635751/jquery-equivalent-browser-compatibility-for-e-parentnode-parentnode-childnodes

Comment: text inside a td is considered as text node

Answer (score 0):

Put the text in a `label`, and then use `text()` on the label instead of the `td`
for example:

```
<td>
   <label id="lblName">krshekrar</label>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" id="UserID"/>
</td>
```