# document.getElementById('email' + (2)).innerText not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jsp, firefox

In a Jsp page, I've a ADD button which dynamically adds a text box with `id ="email"+rowindex`.

When I try to fetch the value of the email added through `document.getElementById('email' + (2)).innerText`, where `(2)` is the row index value, it is not working in Firefox, but it works perfectly fine in IE. Please help.

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.innerText` property is non-standard. Use `.textContent` instead.

---

Or if you're supporting older IE, then you can do it like this:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email' + 2);

var text = email.textContent || email.innerText;
```

Comment: if it is latest IE then, same value will be appended

Answer (score 0):

This little code might be of Help

```
var email = document.getElementById('email' + (2));
var text = email.value;
```

Hope this Helps!