# return false in firefox causing ajax timing issue i'm thinking

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a simple ajax page that adds 2 numbers.

When I run in IE, the async callback works.

When I run in Firefox it doesn't work.

I get the correct return value in Firebug but lblSum remains blank in Firefox.

It has something to do with the **return false** at the end of the btnAdd click handler.

There is a server-side handler in case Javascript is disabled, so in the Javascript I add a return false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pageWebForm1 = {
        txt1: document.getElementById('TextBox1'),
        txt2: document.getElementById('TextBox2'),
        lblSum: document.getElementById('LblSum'),
        btnAdd: document.getElementById('BtnAdd'),
        init: function() {
            this.btnAdd.onclick = function() {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                        xhrCallback(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }
                xhr.open("POST", "Handler.ashx", true);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xhr.send("x=" + pageWebForm1.txt1.value + "&" + "y=" + pageWebForm1.txt2.value);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    pageWebForm1.init();

    function xhrCallback(retval) {
        pageWebForm1.lblSum.innerText = retval;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: No errors. I actually get the correct response as well. It just never makes it to the lblSum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the return false statement. Your problem is innerText is IE only. Another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) on a cross-browser solution.

Comment: That was it, thank you. Sorry, if too easy. Haven't been a hit lately to SO experts.