# Why does this onMouseOut event not fire in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’ve seen this issue before but have found no concrete answers so far. I have an `onmouseout` event which works in practically everything but Firefox. It’s not even showing up in Firebug, which makes no sense at all.

Here are the offending lines of code:

```
<div id="MarketBox3" class="MarketBox" style="top: 205px;">
<div id="TimeBox3Cont" class="TimeBox"><h3 ifirefoxd="TimeBox3" style="color: white; text-     shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 12px;"></h3></div>
<div id="TimeBar3" class="TimeBar" style="left: 300px; width: 300px;" onmouseover="CheckOpen(3)" onmouseout="document.getElementById('intext3').innerText = 'bla bla'">
<div id="MarketName3" class="MarketName">
<div id="inbox3" style="position: absolute; top: -2px; height: 30px; width: 300px;">
<h3 id="intext3" style="color: white; text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 16px;">Frankfurt - Germany</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone have a crack at what’s going on? It literally works fine in everything except Firefox.

Comment: any errors / warnings in Firebug console ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works just fine:

```
<div id="MarketBox3" class="MarketBox" style="top: 205px;">
<div id="TimeBox3Cont" class="TimeBox"><h3 id="TimeBox3" style="color: white; text-     shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 12px;"></h3></div>
<div id="TimeBar3" class="TimeBar" style="left: 300px; width: 300px;" onmouseover="document.getElementById('intext3').innerText = '111'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('intext3').innerText = 'bla bla'">
<div id="MarketName3" class="MarketName">
<div id="inbox3" style="position: absolute; top: -2px; height: 30px; width: 300px;">
<h3 id="intext3" style="color: white; text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 16px;">Frankfurt - Germany</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrT8D/4/).

There might be a problem with your **CheckOpen()** function,

Try

```
onmouseover="alert(1)"

onmouseout="alert(2)"
```

instead of

```
onmouseover="CheckOpen(3)"
```

#### Another Suggestion

It seems that [Firefox treats **innerText** differently than other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).

Using a javascript library will erase this problem because it will automatically take care of differences in browser behavior.

I tried using jQuery and it works fine.

```
<div id="MarketBox3" class="MarketBox" style="top: 205px;">
<div id="TimeBox3Cont" class="TimeBox"><h3 id="TimeBox3" style="color: white; text-     shadow: 0px 0px 5px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 12px;"></h3></div>
<div id="TimeBar3" class="TimeBar" style="left: 300px; width: 300px;" onmouseover="javasript:function f(){ $('#intext3').text('bla bla');} f(); " onmouseout="javasript:function g(){ $('#intext3').text('1111');} g(); ">
<div id="MarketName3" class="MarketName">
<div id="inbox3" style="position: absolute; top: -2px; height: 30px; width: 300px;">
<h3 id="intext3" style="color: white; text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000; letter-spacing: 1px; font-size: 16px;">Frankfurt - Germany</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrT8D/28/).

Comment: Ive already tried this and just about everything else I can think of, nothing works, Ive also changed my version of firefox just to make sure it wasn't a bug with that particular version.
But thanks for the suggestion =)

Comment: Interestingly, the jsfiddle doesn't work... Hmmm
Im going to try another computer

Comment: I've defined a function in the onmousout event, and it works fine. The problem seems to be with document.getElementById('intext3').innerText = 'bla bla'

Comment: Thanks for the help, your quite correct and it shouldn't have been in there at all, I did a find and replace on all 'innerText' entries to 'textContent' but somehow those got missed haha.