# Javascript not work with FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [‘innerText’ works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

```
function stopped() {
    var this_row =  document.getElementById("row_1");
    var cells = this_row.getElementsByTagName("td");

    $('#starttime').html(cells[0].innerText);     
}
```

I have a javascript function above. It fills a form using the value from cells[0]. It works with IE and Chrome. But it cannot work with FireFox browser. I want to know whther there is any problem with my code. Thanks.

Comment: If you have jquery why not simply `var cells = $("#row_1 td")`?

Comment: Yes. If you're using jQuery, then use jQuery... If you're using pure Javascript, then use pure Javascript. I really don't like developers mixing the two without any particular performance-related reasons.

Comment: Why you are using pure Javascript selector and later `Jquery` selectors? Can I see the html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$(cells[0]).text();
```

instead of

```
cells[0].innerText
```

innerText is a property introduced by IE and is not a w3c-standard(and not supported by firefox).

Comment: Why would this solve his issue?

Comment: because jQuery's text()-method isn't based on innerText

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I wasn't saying it wouldn't. I was asking for an explanation.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: Does my answer provide spec-related explanation for it?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: It work because Jquery is a cross browser library, that's one of the advantages of using jQuery ;)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, yes everything is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

### The problem is `innerText`

The problem with your code is (as [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13498358/75642) also pointed out) the use of `innerText` property which Firefox doesn't understand as can be seen on [QuirksMode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04).

Firefox instead understands `textContent` property.

### The solution

Rewrite your function to embrace jQuery and it should work cross-browser because jQuery was written to be a cross-browser library (to make our life easier with individual browser quirks):

```
function stopped() {
    $("#starttime").html($("#row_1 td:first-child").text());
}
```