# jQuery .text() equivalent that converts <br> tags to whitespace

Tags: jquery, html, whitespace, line-breaks

It's trivial to get the text from a jQuery selection:

```
<span id="foo">hello world</span>

$('#foo').text();
```

> `hello world`

But when the jQuery selection contains `<br>` tags they are conceptually newlines, which are whitespace. Unfortunately `.text()` strips them completely:

```
<span id="foo">hello<br>world</span>

$('#foo').text();
```

> `helloworld`

How can I extract the text from such a span such that it results in `hello world` instead?

Of course this is a trivial example invented to keep the problem clear. A real answer will need to be "equivalent to `.text()`" and handle arbitrary HTML of course. Here's a slightly more tricky example, also made up:

```
<div id="foo"><span class="bar"><em>hello</em><br></span>world</div>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Mims suggest use `replaceWith()` to change the `<br>` to spaces, but as not to alter the original element use `clone()` to make a clone of the element.

```
var foo = $("#foo").clone();
foo.find("br").replaceWith(" ");
var text = foo.text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/EQwt6/)

Comment: Hmm this works great in jsfiddle, but when I try it in my real code I get `"Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  "` at the `.replaceWith()` ... can't make sense of it yet ...

Comment: @hippietrail Did you copy code directly from jsfiddle? if so try typing it manually.

Comment: <s>Yes in fact the error manifests even if you type this into the debug console on the jsfiddle page. But when "running" the fiddle it's fine.</s> Argh sorry that was a different error due to jsfiddle's iframes I think.

Comment: @hippietrail jsfiddle uses frames, so typing code directly in the console isn't going to work. try http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/EQwt6/show/, its the same fiddle but not in a frame.

Comment: The site I'm scraping is using jQuery v1.4.4, I wonder if that makes a difference.

Comment: This did just work the next time I needed it, which was using node.js with cheerio which only implements subsets of DOM and jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

Use  `.html()` instead of `.text()`

```
$('#foo').html();
```

OR use the DOM method `.innerText`

```
$('#foo')[0].innerText ;
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gavZs/)**

Comment: But when the document I'm extracting from has much less trivial markup than my example I'll be left with an HTML parsing problem no?

Comment: Can you give an example for such situation!!.. Also I don't think that should be a problem

Comment: `<div id="foo"><span class="bar"><em>hello</em><br></span>world</div>`

Comment: If thats the case you can use the innerText method for the DOM Object ... `$('#foo')[0].innerText`

Comment: Aha! Much more expressive and simple - changing my acceptance (-:

Comment: @hippietrail see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: Sorry @Sushanth-- as per Musa's comment I'm forced to unaccept again )-: Damn Firefox - who would've guessed IE would implement something more useful than the other browsers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `replaceWith()` function.

```
$("br").replaceWith(" ");
```

Comment: I was about to post this and put together this relevant fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FCck2/