# jquery .css/.attr/.addClass not working on span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the background colour of a span using jquery. I've used all functions in the title and all give me an error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'css'/'attr'/'addClass'

Any idea how I can solve this? All I want is to change the bg colour however I prefer if I can set the class.

code:

```
var liList = ul.find('li span');
        $.each(liList, function(index, value){
            if(value.innerText == currPage){
                value.css('background-color', '#D94A38');
            }
        });
```

Comment: As Aleksandr said, you need to show your code. We can't see what is wrong until we have something to work with!

Comment: @jerome.s yes I'm using it in the same function which works perfectly

Comment: Watch out for innerText usage on the DOM element as that may [not be supported on all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).  You can use $(value)[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) as an alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value` is not a jQuery object (it's a DOM object).

This:

```
value.css('background-color', '#D94A38');
```

Should be:

```
$(value).css('background-color', '#D94A38');
```

Check out the [`.each()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) for additional information.

Answer (score 7):

The [**each()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function gives you `DOM` object not `jQuery` object

Change to

```
$(value).css('background-color', '#D94A38');
```

Your code would be

```
var liList = ul.find('li span');
    $.each(liList, function(index, value){
        if(value.innerText == currPage){
            $(value).css('background-color', '#D94A38');
        }
});
```

Comment: since @James Hill was the first to answer I have to accept his answer. but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you replace value by $(value) your problem will solved