# Number of Items in Basket popup

Tags: javascript, if-statement, shopping-cart

I hope someone can help

Basically I am looking for a way of creating a popup notification of how many items are in a users shopping basket.

When the user adds an item to their basket a red circle with the number of items appears next to the basket icon and when the number of items in the basket is equal to 0 then the red circle disappears.

This is the JavaScript coding I am trying to write:

```
if(document.querySelector('#no_items').innerText === '0'){
document.querySelector(".circle").style.display = 'none';

} else {
document.querySelector(".circle").style.display= 'inline';

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2bwa/

Basically when the basic is empty the popup disappears but appears when items are added.

Is this possible to do without JQuery?

Comment: Yes, it could be done without jQuery, but not without JavaScript - why not use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here's a reworking of your JSFiddle that does what you want - I haven't reworked it extensively, just enough to provide a working example (I leave using latest / best practice / modular code as an exercise for the OP!):

```
<style>
.circle {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:20px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#be1417;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 17px;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;     /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;  /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: all 1s;       /* Opera */
    -ms-transition: all 1s;      /* IE10+ */
    transition: all 1s;          /* W3C */
}
</style>
<script>
    function checkValue() {
        if (document.getElementById("no_items").innerHTML === '0') {
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.MozTransform = "scale(0)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.WebkitTransform = "scale(0)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.OTransform = "scale(0)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.msTransform = "scale(0)";
        } else {
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.MozTransform = "scale(1)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.WebkitTransform = "scale(1)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.OTransform = "scale(1)";
            document.querySelector(".circle").style.msTransform = "scale(1)";
        }
    }

    function incrementValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('no_items').innerHTML, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        value++;
        document.getElementById('no_items').innerHTML = value;
        checkValue();
    }

    function decrementValue() {
        var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('no_items').innerHTML, 10);
        value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
        (value >= 1) && value--;
        document.getElementById('no_items').innerHTML = value;
        checkValue();
    }
</script>
<div id="circle" class="circle">
    <div id="no_items" style="color:white">1</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="incrementValue()" value="Buy Item" />
<input type="button" onclick="decrementValue()" value="Remove Item" />
```

#### However, this is not fully cross-browser compatible.

It works fine in the latest Firefox, Opera, Chrome and IE, but the mileage will vary for older versions.

A couple of errors in your original script:

- querySelector selects on CSS classname not element ID - use getElementById for IDs
- innerText is IE-specific, innerHTML is safe to use here instead - see ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

and a few points in general:

From your JSFiddle it looks like you want to animate showing/hiding the red circle. I've stuck with your scale method, but be aware it can depend on the browser as to which CSS properties are supported by CSS transitions.

I don't know why this has to be done without jQuery, as it removes a lot of the cross-browser issues with trying to do this sort of thing, and makes it very easy to apply visibility/style changes and animate them.
However, if you need to write it all from scratch, it's going to be better and more flexible if you create CSS classes for your visible/hidden states and apply them using the technique detailed in [Change an element's class with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript) - that way you don't keep having to change the JS code every time you want to change the styling.

Good luck!