# Passing JSON string to MVC controller does not work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

In an asp.net mvc 4 web application I have a kendo grid (named ExternalUserList) where I have added a custom column with checkboxes in order to send an email to selected users. What I do is send the database id of the user(s) in json format to my mvc controller.

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMailToExternalUsers() {
        var ids = [];
        var proId;
        var checkBox = $('#ExternalUsersList > table > tbody > tr td:nth-child(2) > input');

        checkBox.each(function (index) {
            var $input = $(this);

            if ($input.is(':checked')) {
                var count = index + 1;
                proId = $('#ExternalUsersList > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(' + count + ') td:first-child');
                ids.push(proId[0].innerText);
            }
        })

        var postData = JSON.stringify(ids);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/ExternalUser/SendEmailToExternalUsers/",
            data: postData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            traditional: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

and here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public EmptyResult SendEmailToExternalUsers(List<string> ids)
{
   //Here i do some processing
}
```

All the above code works fine in Internet Explorer and Chrome but on Firefox it does not. In fact if i have selected for example 3 users from the kendo grid, visual studio debugger shows that ids `List<string>` has 3 elements but values are empty. In IE and Chrome values are perfectly correct.

So is wrong with it?

Comment: Did you use Firebug to check for javascript errors or any server results?

Comment: @Rob There are no javascript errors but the line of code proId[0].innerText returns undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most probably something related to your client-side code. I'd guess it is this line

```
ids.push(proId[0].innerText);
```

Try to debug that with Firebug to see what gets returned. You might also want to use the jQuery's methods `.text()` or `.html()` depending on what you're interested in.

Comment: You are right the problem is in this line of code. prodId[0].innerText and prodId[0].text() are both undefined. prodId[0].html() raises an exception.

Comment: @VimalStan I am sorry but i cannot accept the answer as it is not the solution to the problem. It is only a suggestion.

Comment: @GiorgosManoltzas The "solution" is to rely on the .text() or .html() functions of jQuery which work cross-browser. See this SO question for clarifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox