# Manipulating HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to manipulate the text that is already inside the div and replace it with another strings from JavaScript, creating a basic animating effect by replacing particular character from strings present inside the div element, more precisely position based replacement of string. However when I wrote down the following code it doesn't work. What I wanted to do is that store the original text in one variable and when the dom replacement of text occurs then setting certain interval replace by the old text and again replace by the new randomize text creating text replacement animation in certain position of the text.

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var all ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa{}[];:></?bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123+_)(*&^%$#@!~`456789";
var old_text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;

function randChar() {
    "use strict";
    return all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length));   
}
function main() {
    "use strict";
    var $_inter = setInterval(function() {

        var text = document.getElementById("text");

        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, 5) + randChar() + text.innerHTML.substring(5);
        setTimeout(function(){
            text.innerHTML = old_text;
        },200);
    }, 350);
}
window.onload = main;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="text">Hello World!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So in order to make it work for a while I used the original string as

```
setTimeout(function(){
            text.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
        },200);
```

Which is not possible as the text in page might have been generated dynamically. When I did run the first code it says innerText of Null.

The exact error it throws is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

What does that mean, because text and element is there why can't it grab the text from dom?

Comment: text is not set inside of the setTimeout()-function?

Comment: shouldn't it be able to grab from the top declared old_text as every other variable can be accessed like the 'all' can be accessed from randChar() why old_text can't be ?

Comment: What is  the use of the `flag` variable?

Comment: @sann sorry about that, i forgot to remove it, it not functional in this code, i will update it right now

Comment: @monk there ain't no use of `counter` variable too.

Comment: yes, before i was using it to randomly access the characters.for simplicity i used the number 5 for the position

Comment: I was wrong about the text-variable. I wasn't thinking clear enough. I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Your problem is being cause because you're getting `#text` before it is defined.

```
var old_text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
```

You should include this in your `window.onload` function as it will exist then.

### Uncaught ReferenceError: flag is not defined

Once you do that you will receiving another error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: flag is not defined

For the line:

```
flag = flag+1;
```

This is because you have not defined your flag variable, this can be fixed by defining `var flag;` at the top of your first.

### Demo

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/JUzQF/1/)

```
var all ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa{}[];:></?bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123+_)(*&^%$#@!~`456789";
var old_text;
var flag = 0;

function randChar() {
    "use strict";
    return all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length));   
}
function main() {
    "use strict";
    old_text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
    var counter = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.getElementById("text").innerText.length);
    var $_inter = setInterval(function() {

        var text = document.getElementById("text");

        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, 5) + randChar() + text.innerHTML.substring(5);
        setTimeout(function(){
            text.innerHTML = old_text;
        },200);
        flag = flag+1;
    }, 350);
}
window.onload = main;
```

### Error in Firefox

With the above code we're still receiving the original error in Firefox. This is because [Firefox doesn't implement innerText](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359507/1156119). This can be fixed by using either `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JUzQF/2/)

```
old_text = document.getElementById("text").textContent;
var counter = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.getElementById("text").textContent.length);
// or
old_text = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML;
var counter = Math.floor(Math.random()*document.getElementById("text").innerHTML.length);
```

Comment: this throws a `TypeError: document.getElementById(...).innerText is undefined` error on `var counter = Math.floor(Math.random() * document.getElementById("text").innerText.length);` in firefox 19.0.2 for me. If I replace `innerText` with `innerHTML` in said line, the output is "undef_ned" with "_" being replaced with random chars. Any thoughts?

Comment: yes, i couldn't run it on firefox as well, but in chrome it works perfectly

Comment: Perfect. +1 for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
var all ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZa{}[];:></?bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123+_)(*&^%$#@!~`456789";
var old_text;

function randChar() {
    "use strict";
    return all.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*all.length));   
}
function main() {
    "use strict";
    old_text = document.getElementById("text").innerText;
    var $_inter = setInterval(function() {
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.substring(0, 5) + randChar() + text.innerHTML.substring(5);
        setTimeout(function(){
            text.innerHTML = old_text;
        },200);
    }, 350);
}
window.onload = main;
```

Just get rid of `flag` and `counter`. Initialize `old_text` in the `onload` listener.

Comment: In firefox 19.0.2, the output is `undef_ned` with `_` being replaced with random chars.