# Climb on the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I read all the `td` cells from the certain column if I know which row to read.

Let me illustrate this:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    ....
</tr>
```

At some point I know that I need to read value `0` and I want to know all of the other `td` in that row.

So in some loop I have this:

```
selected[i][0]
```

which is giving me : `<input type="checkbox" value="0">`
`var i` is going from `0`

How to get all the items?

I have tried with : `$('tr').eq(i).find('td').eq(1).text()`

and it is not giving me the right values.

Comment: What do you mean 'read' the `td` cell, what is it you're looking to get?

Comment: You can get all cells in row, if you selected first one, by using siblings()?

Comment: Can we see more `html` how do we know where the next column will be?

Comment: Your illustration isn't too clear. What do you want to be the *result* of this? I.e. what does "all the other `td` in that row" mean, and why do you say "from the certain column" at the start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At some point I know that I need to read value 0 and I want to know
>   all of the other td in that row.

If I am understanding you correctly, this should give you your intended results using the jQuery library:

```
$("td input[value='0']").parent().parent().children("td").each(function(){
    alert($(this).text()); //Replace alert with however you want to output your data
});
```

**Explanation:**

`$("td input[value='0']")` will select all `<input />` tags with the attribute `value` set to 0, contained within a `<td>` tag

`.parent()` will go to the parent `<td>` tag

`.parent()` will go to the parent `<tr>` tag

`.children("td")` will select all of the `<td>` tags contained within the respective `tr` tag

`.each(function(){...})` will do something with those `<td>` tags

`$(this).text()` will select the `<td>`'s text

Answer (score 2):

Protip: Learn to use the awesome Firebug console to get **direct** output of selected elements - that's the way to intuitive code Javascript :-)

```
$('tr').eq(i).children('td').children('input').val()
```

maybe, but that's your turn.

[image]

Comment: +1 for firebug console

Comment: I am familiar with Firebug...but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the following `helps`,
http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/

```
<script>
    function load(){
        var table = document.getElementById("mtable");
        for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
           if(table.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByClassName('valTd')[0].value==0){
               for (var j = 1, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
                 alert(table.rows[i].cells[j].innerText);
               } 
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<body onload="load()">
<table id="mtable">    
    <tr>
        <td><input class='valTd' type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td><input class='valTd' type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>John</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
```

Comment: @user123_456 see if this helps, pure JS

Comment: Good, just instead of the [innerText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) use something more compatible, and also better compatible than `.getElementsByClassName` is here `.getElementsByTagName` or `.querySelector`: http://jsfiddle.net/sLBgY/1/

Answer (score 0):

if your html will look like this

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="0"></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Julie</td>
</tr>
```

then you would simply do this

```
   $('tr').each(function( index, element) {
      var $element = $(element),
          checkbox = $element.children(0)[0];
          id = $element.children(1); 
          name = $element.children(2);
   });
```

> **[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/FVNkx/)**

Answer (score 0):

This will find all the cells in the correct row:

```js
$(function () {
    var found = false;
    $('table tr').each(function () {
        var cells = $(this).children('td');
        if (cells.eq(0).find('input').val() == 0) { // the value you're looking for
            found = cells;
        }
    });
    if (found) {
        alert(found.eq(0).html() + found.eq(1).html() + found.eq(2).html());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7VmR9/16/