# DOM element's style property is an empty string when accessed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following style defined for an element with ID #foo.

```
#foo {
    display: none;
}
```

I run the following JavaScript code:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo')
alert('[' + foo.style.display + ']')
```

I was expecting the output to be `[none]`. However, the output is simply `[]`. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bEmUE/

Why is foo.style.display an empty string here?

What can I write in the code to figure the actual display property of this element?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The style attribute only gives you information about inline styles.

> However, it is not useful for learning about the element's style in
>   general, since it represents only the CSS declarations set in the
>   element's inline style attribute, not those that come from style rules
>   elsewhere, such as style rules in the  section, or external
>   style sheets.
>
> <sub>Source: [MDN HTMLElement.style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style)</sub>

Instead you should use this:

```
getComputedStyle(foo).display;
```

### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bEmUE/2/)

Comment: It seems like 'innerText' (used in your example) is not cross browser compatible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: Thanks, I updated the fiddle to use jQuery (wasn't relevant to the question, just for demo purposes).

Comment: @Whistletoe - His demo uses innertext to only demonstrate a solution to what the OP has asked and is in no way part of the solution! So thanks for the heads up, but it's irrelevant!

Comment: Yeah, i was just mystified why the fiddle didn't work for me.