# Firefox & IE does not run innertext

Tags: javascript

I have a problem like this :

```
<div id='stickyid' style='display:block; color:red'>happi</div>
After write :
<script type="text/javascript">
var thevalue = document.getElementById("stickyid").innerText;
document.write(""+thevalue+""); 
</script>
```

It runs ok on Chrome but not Firefox and IE. How can I fix it?

Comment: In this case `.innerHTML` would yield the same result? Firefox uses `.textContent` - which is the W3C recommendation I believe - see this [table of compatabilities](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
var thevalue = document.getElementById("stickyid").innerText || document.getElementById("stickyid").textContent;
```

Answer (score 2):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E3ESv/

```
var thevalue = document.getElementById("stickyid").textContent;
```

Please visit ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) for more help