# Eval doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, eval

As simple as the title says.

I have a bunch of scripts that work over some javascript code and should execute that code when pressing a button. 
I use the eval function to do that and it works fine on:

- GOOGLE CHROME
- SAFARI
- OPERA
- INTERNET EXPLORER (?!?)

Surprisingly this doesn't work on Firefox and if I open the console here is the error I get: 
[12:17:58.447] ReferenceError: undefinedundefinedundefinedundefinedundefined is not defined

Any idea on how to make it work even on FF?

EDIT.
here's the code I use. so much to work on!

```
function exec_code() {
   var code= document.getElementById("code").innerText;
   eval (code);
}
```

Comment: No, we have no idea how to make the code we can't see work on Firefox. (But if you are using `eval` then you are probably doing something highly sub-optimal anyway).

Comment: don't be so nervous.. look at the code and be a little bit more kind the next time. I don't really know how that 2 lines of code can be helpful. Since everything work fine everywhere I really doubt that the problem is the code!

Comment: Yes. So much to work on. **What is the value of `code`**? and where does `exec` come from?

Comment: Really hard to tell what you're trying to do with this, but are you sure you really need to use `eval()`?

Answer (score 4):

Firefox [doesn't support the non-standard `innerText`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) property.

You can establish this by testing the value of `code` before you pass it to `exec`. It will be `undefined`.

Use something else to get your data.