# JavaScript undefined variable getting value from page class

Tags: javascript

I have a bookmarklet which takes some information from the page the user current is on which they an then save to there account.
One such peace of information is a price of an item they might be looking at. To grab the price from the page I have the below javascript:

```
input = this.createInput("price", "hidden");
var prices=new Array("price","kfs-price","pricesize","salesprice","money","ourPrice","product-price","memo_fp_prix_final"
              ,"atrPrice","product_price");
      var price = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < prices.length; i++){
          var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName(prices[i]);
          for (var a = 0; a < priceEls.length; a++) {
            price = priceEls[a].innerText;
            i = 1000;
          } 
      }
      input.setAttribute("value", price);
      this.form.appendChild(input);
```

The prices array is based on looking at some common well known sites and what class name they give for the area the price is put into.
How even on pages that for example have a price class name the variable 'price' when added to the form still comes back 'undefined'.

I cant see anything wrong with the code so was hoping someone can see the issue or knows of a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with innerHTML : http://jsfiddle.net/vDFpR/

```
for (var a = 0; a < priceEls.length; a++) {
    price = priceEls[a].innerHTML;
    i = 1000;
}
```

it's may be related to this : ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

i think this line

```
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName(prices[i]);
// taking an instance of this inside the loop 
var priceEls = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
```

Now i don't understand your innerloop

```
for (var a = 0; a < priceEls.length; a++) {
        price = priceEls[a].innerText;
        i = 1000;
      }

priceEls is giving you an element only
```

what is this line doing

```
//price = priceEls[a].innerText;
```

Comment: `price = priceEls[a].innerText;` should return the text within the element no?