# document.getelementById().innerText doesn't on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Need use javascript get a asp.net label text, below javascript works fine for IE and Chrome, but not Firefox, how to make it work for all browsers.

```
function showThumbnails_OnClick() {

        var id = document.getElementById('lblId').innerText;

        if (ChkBox.checked) {
            location.href = 'Result.aspx?Id=' + id;
        }

    }

<asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text="">
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to write a function that handle both cases:

```
function showThumbnails_OnClick() {
    var element = document.getElementById('lblId');
    var id = element.innerText || element.textContent;

    if (ChkBox.checked) {
        location.href = 'Result.aspx?Id=' + id;
    }

}
```

Comment: textContent is not equivalent to innerHTML (eg newlines) see http://clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent/

Comment: @JimW yes it is not. never said it was. it only returns the text without any html in it. Maybe that's exactly what the op needs

Comment: @JimW This solution solves the OP's problem. Just because textContent and innerHTML aren't equivalent doesn't mean that you downvote the answers that solve the problem.

Comment: @Rohit my bad, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

Change `.innerText` to `.textContent`

Comment: textContent is not equivalent to innerHTML (eg newlines) see clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent

Comment: It's not but, it does solve the problem that the OP is having.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure it will work on IE and FF.

```
var c_id = document.getElementById("lblId");
var id = (c_id.textContent == undefined) ? c_id.innerText : c_id.textContent;
```