# jQuery each function inside another jQuery each function to split out data to be used in the first each function

Tags: jquery, variables, loops, split, each

Ok, I apologize for not posting the full question the first time, I got beat up pretty bad by the community so here's my second attempt:

I have a UL of LIs in each Article on my page, I want to use JavaScript (jQuery) to grab the text I am looking for in the LIs and drop that text into each Article as classes, so I can filter them with jQuery Isotope. The problem is that the value I am looking for in each LI needs to be split out, and so far my attempts have failed when trying to split the values out from the whole UL, I need to convert spaces into dashes etc, so I'm thinking I need to run another each function just for the LIs, so far all attempts have failed here as well.

Example HTML of one Article on my page:

```
<article id="post-136" class="isotope-item">
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="ct-custom-field-block">
            <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Species:</span> Walnut Claro</li>
            <li>
                <span>Product Type:</span> Slab</li>
            <li>
                <span>Tag Number:</span> xxxx</li>
            <li>
                <span>PN:</span> xxxx</li>
            <li>
                <span>BF:</span> xx.xx</li>
            <li>
                <span>Weight (lbs):</span> xxx.xx</li>
            <li>
                <span>Width (in):</span> 25-42</li>
            <li>
                <span>Length (in):</span> 73-96</li>
            <li>
                <span>Depth (in):</span> 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- .entry-content -->
</article>
```

The jQuery: I need to split out each LI separately within the loop for each Article, and so far I've hit a mental wall, I don't know where to look for this kind of question, I know there's a concept here I haven't figured out yet, any explanation or tip is much appreciated!

```
function prepareIso() {

    // loop on each <article>
    $('article').each(function() {

      // the list of data I need for this article
      var data = $(this).find('.ct-custom-field-block ul');

      // some amazing regex replace or split that can return each individual value I need, unfortunately I don't have a better solution than this replace chain, which doesn't give enough control to create classes with hyphens and remove irrelevant data
      // var dataHTML = data.html();
      // var outPut = dataHTML.replace("Species: ","").replace("Product Type:","").replace("Tag Number:","").replace("PN:","").replace("BF:","").replace("Weight (lbs):","").replace("Width (in):","").replace("Length (in):","").replace("Depth (in):","")

      // So I think I need another loop here, just for the LIs this time
        $(data).find('li').each(function() {
            $(this).html().split('</span> ')
            // ??? I am stuck here, I can split the LI's data but I don't know how to grab the second value and collect them into a string.
            var outPut = $(this)[1] // ??? trying to collect the second value after the split of each LI
            // I also need to run a regex replace in this loop to replace spaces with hyphens.
            // But, I need each "Class" to be separated by a space
            // Shouldn't have a problem stripping out the HTML elements
            // outPut should theoretically look something like this at this point
            // var outPut = 'Walnut-Claro Slab xxxx 25-42 73-96 5'
        });

        // now it's easy, just force the data to lower case and add as classes to the Article.
      var classesToAdd = outPut.toLowerCase();
      $(this).addClass(classesToAdd)

    });

}
```

So I've essentially hit a wall at the second each function for the LIs, I know how to split the data and grab the second value if it's just one LI, but how can I run that as a loop on all LIs and keep only the split[1] values.

I hope this is a sufficient explanation of my problem. I just don't know what this is called, doing something like this, I would love to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing a ton of splits, use RegExp to isolate the substrings that you want:

```
function prepareIso() {
  // loop on each <article>
  $('article').each(function() {
      var classList = [];

      // the list of data I need for this article
      var data = $(this).find('.ct-custom-field-block ul');

      $(data).find('li').each(function() {
          var text = this.innerText;
          text = text.replace(/^.*:\s/, '');
          console.log(text);
          classList.push(text.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-').replace('.', '_'));
      });

      $(this).addClass(classList.join(' '));
  });
};
```

Note that I convert spaces to dashes and periods to underscores before setting the class on the article. After the function, the article class looks like this: `isotope-item walnut-claro slab xxxx xx_xx xxx_xx 25-42 73-96 5`

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ToddT/BCS2A/

Comment: Alright! I think the answer here for me is the brush up on my Regex! 
Someone Upvote this because I can't! Thank you! Great advice!

Comment: Sure. If it ends up working out for you, don't forget to select it as the answer. Cheers.

Comment: So I actually ran into a few more challenges along the way, one being, that .innerText is not supported by Firefox, and another, when jQuery returns the variable using .text() (cross browser) it comes with a new line above the info I need. So I rewrote the .replace reg expression to erase the extra line, then do everything else exactly the same. Tada! Now working in Firefox.
text.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '').replace(/^.*:\s/, '');

Comment: Nice. Didn't know FF didn't like `innerText`. Good to know.

Comment: Yeah FF uses .textContent and it's one of those long winded debates where IE uses .innerText and Opera uses both, where FF is the only one that doesn't understand .innerText, but it has valid reasons for doing so etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox