# TextNode or innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

Supposing we have the following element `<p id="abc">Hello World</p>`. If I want to modify the content in the `<p>` tag I have two ways in the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="good morning";
document.getElementById("abc").firstChild.nodeValue="good morning";
```

The questions are:

- Which are the difference between the 2 solutions?
- Which one should I use? Is there one better than the other?

Comment: Suggested reading: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/1273830  2) http://kellegous.com/j/2013/02/27/innertext-vs-textcontent/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first one will erase any HTML elements that might be inside your target element. The second will only work if the first child is a text node (a common mistake is to try and use it on an empty element).

The second is "more correct" (`innerHTML` is really a haxy shortcut) but the first is certainly more reliable. That said, it is vulnerable to XSS injections.

To be completely correct, you would do this:

```
var abc = document.getElementById('abc');
while(abc.firstChild) abc.removeChild(abc.firstChild);
abc.appendChild(document.createTextNode("good morning"));
```