# getElementBy ID not returning for label tag

Tags: javascript, label

getElementById does not return any value. My objective is I have a text content and 
upon a action I have to replace the value of the text. I use labels to display.
    Is there any better way to display such modified text, I dont want to use textbox.

```
<% for(int i=0; i<lines.length;i++) {
  if(lines[i].contains(" ")) { %>
   <label id='idkey<%=i%>' name='key1<%=i%>'>ABC</label>
                          <%
  }
} %>


for(j=0; j<len; j++){
var lblElement = document.getElementById('idkey'+j).innerText="ddd";
  alert(lblElement);
}
```

Comment: If it doesn't return a value, then there's no element on the page with that "id".

Comment: What browser are you using? By "not returning any value", do you mean the alert is blank?

Comment: possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: good @epascarello I have forgot that innerText doesn't work with FF

Comment: I would recommend to consider to accept an answer. Currently you have 4 questions and no accepted answer. People are less inclined to help if you do not acceppt answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re hi,

I think your Id is wrong, innerText work properly with http://jsfiddle.net/mPc2E/
Be carreful, innerText return the value of you new text, not the modified tag.

```
document.getElementById('lab').innerText = " toto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.getElementById('idkey'+j).innerHTML = 'ddd';
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6sJb4/)

Comment: innerHTML is for set new content html with tag, prefer use innerText in order to set a simple text at a tag :)

Answer (score 0):

The line `var lblElement = document.getElementById('idkey'+j).innerText="ddd";` does not set `lblElement` equal to the element - but rather equal to the text `"ddd"`.
Try the following in stead:

```
for(j=0; j<len; j++){
  var lblElement = document.getElementById('idkey'+j);
  lblElement.innerText="ddd";
  alert(lblElement);
}
```

*Note:* This assumes that the `len` variable contains the correct value