# Spelling game score points using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a spelling game that uses JavaScript.

Currently when the word is spelled correctly it will display a message.

```
if(++score >= str.length) {
    var text = 'Well done! The correct word is ' + str + '!'
    drawBackground(background, images.back, text);
}
```

I would like to display one point for each correct word and increment it.
This is what i have tried but no luck

```
function points() {
    var points = 0;    
    if(++score >= str.length) {    
        points++;
        document.getElementById("points").innerText="Score: " + points; 
    }
}
```

The HTML to display the score

```
<p>Score: <span id="points"></span></p>
```

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? What happens or doesn't happen? Check the dev console for errors?

Comment: Won't `points` always be 1? Why not use `score`?

Comment: Your HTML is going to repeat "Score: ". You change the innerText of #points to "Score: ", but "Score: " is already in the <p>. So it'd be "Score: Score: 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems with your code:

- The value of `points` is being reset to `0` every time you enter the `points()` function. You must move `var points = 0` outside of `points()`, making it a global variable.
- As you cannot have a function and a global variable with the same name, you must rename the `points` variable (e.g. to `numPoints`).
- [The `el.innerText` property will only work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox). Replace it `el.textContent`.

Improved version of your code:

```
let numPoints = 0;    

function points() {
    if(++score >= str.length) {    
        numPoints++;
        document.getElementById("points").textContent = "Score: " + numPoints; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't tell for sure, but won't `points` inside the function refer to the function itself?

Comment: `innerHTML` is not required... `innerText` will work just fine. (If the OP were inserting HTML into the DOM, it would be a different story.)

Comment: @pete That shows exactly how much I understand the DOM. Edited

Comment: Also, there is such a thing as `++score` in JavaScript... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators

Comment: I have just tried this, when I spell the word correct the var text displays from my original code but the score doesn't display. It just says score:

Comment: @MistressDavid Thanks for trying, but i can't get it to work, it must be something I'm missing or not seeing in the previous code. It was made by a freelancer.