# how do I put some text between the a href taggs?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript
I've created this code and it almost works.
The href works but how do I put the fixed phonenumber between the **a href** taggs?

`document.write` does not work.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fix(nummer) {
            var nieuw = nummer.replace(/\D/g,'');
            var output = document.getElementById("nummer");
            var href = 'http://10.0.1.151/?call=' + nieuw;
            output.setAttribute("href", href);
            output.document.write(nieuw);
        }
    </script>
    <label>Typ telefoonummer</label><input id="telefoon" style="margin-left: 30px" type="text" onblur="fix(this.value)" />
    <span><a target="_blank" id="nummer">Call [how do I get the fixed number here??]</a></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`element.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent):

```
document.getElementById('nummer').textContent = "Call " + nummer;
```

[`innerText` is an IE thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).

Comment: You are right! innerText didn't work on Chrome. textContent works perfectly now

Comment: innerHTML should work on all browsers, which is why I suggested it

Answer (score 3):

Set the `innerText` property of the element.

```
output.innerText = "Call "+nummer;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var phoneNum = document.getElementById('number');
phoneNum.innerHTML=("Call " + phoneNumberToCall); //Could also use phoneNum.innerText
```

Comment: innerHTML is not a function.

Comment: @bjb568, just a typo. There was supposed to be an "=" in there. Are you the one who keeps trolling my posts?