# javascript: alert values of a table row

Tags: javascript, html, tablerow

I'm trying to alert only values without html tags from a selected table row. What's wrong with the following function:

```
        function show_table_row(row) {
            var arr = [];
            var t_row = document.getElementById("table_id").rows[row].innerHTML;
            for (var i = 0; i < t_red.length; i++)
            {
               arr.push(t_row [i]);
            }
            alert(arr.join("\n"));
        }
```

Comment: Where are you calling this function? What's the value of `row` being passed to the function..? How does the html look like, does it only have text nodes or does it have inner HTML content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your innerHTML to innerText

```
var t_row = document.getElementById("table_id").rows[row].innerText;
```

Edit:- Thanks to Alex W for poitning out , you can use .textContent , since firefox does not support innerText. It is otherwise supported on all major browsers. But note that .textContent is not supported on older versions of IE (before IE9) http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `.textContent` because `.innerText` is not a standardized W3 property.

['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: Thank you Alex, that's what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Use    `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`