# In Firefox kendo button text is not changing while in IE and Chrome working

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, kendo-ui, innertext

Here is my code:

```
$("#autogeneraterfid2").change(function () {
  // debugger
  if ($("#autogeneraterfid2").is(':checked')) {
    var kButton = $("#btnsaveprint").data("kendoButton");
    kButton.element[0].innerText = "Save and Program RFID";
  } else {
    var kButton = $("#btnsaveprint").data("kendoButton");
    kButton.element[0].innerText = "Save & Print";
  }
});
```

On checkbox change am changing the `innerText` of kendo button. This works fine in IE and Chrome whereas in Firefox it is not working.

Can anyone tell me what is the exact problem?

Comment: create a fiddle and post your html code

Comment: try using innerHTML rather than innerText. I have seen this happen before where one works in one browser and doesn't work in an other browser. innerHTML still works in IE and Chrome

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with a possible solution. http://jsfiddle.net/YF49U/

This is using the kendo button demo as a template and then just hooking your code onto the first primary button.

You will notice that I changed the lines:

```
kButton.element[0].innerText =
```

to

```
kButton.element[0].innerHTML =
```