# Constructing HTML table in JavaScript, from Acces DB via ADODB

Tags: javascript, html, ms-access, adodb

As a JavaScript noob, I have just made a little script, that constructs a table from data in an Access Database. But it takes 30 seconds to construct the table, even though the data only consists of 1720 lines. How can I improve that time? (I only have JavaScript, not PHP etc.)

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loadDB() {
    var body = document.body,
        tbl  = document.createElement('table');
    tbl.style.width='100px';
    tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
    var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    var ConnString = "Data Source=S:/queries.accdb;;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;";
    connection.open(ConnString);
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rs.Open("SELECT * from tblPosterSager", connection);
    rs.MoveFirst();
    while (!rs.eof) {
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        var Team = tr.insertCell();
        Team.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Team")));
        Team.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Ktonr = tr.insertCell();
        Ktonr.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Account")));
        Ktonr.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Valuedate = tr.insertCell();
        Valuedate.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields    ("Valuedate")));
        Valuedate.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Valuta = tr.insertCell();
        Valuta.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Currency")));
        Valuta.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Belob = tr.insertCell();
        Belob.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Amount")));
        Belob.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var DC = tr.insertCell();
        DC.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("DC")));
        DC.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Stjerne = tr.insertCell();
        Stjerne.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Star")));
        Stjerne.style.border = "1px solid black";
        var Kommentar = tr.insertCell();
        Kommentar.appendChild(document.createTextNode(rs.fields("Comment")));
        Kommentar.style.border = "1px solid black";
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
    rs.close();
    connection.close();
    body.appendChild(tbl);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an interpreted language, Javascript is slower and Access db is too. To get an accurate picture, you should time the individual processes of your application: how long it takes to read the database (creating it and looping over it the recordset) withtout creating the HTML elements; how long it takes to create the tbl element without inserting; how long it takes to insert it into the body document, etc.

However, Without testing it, I won't be surprised to learn that the building of the tbl element and its insertion are the two slowest processes; so instead of build it using dynamic nodes; you should instead build your new HTML as a plain text and use an assignation innerText to insert it.  This will cause some problems outside of IE, so see ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) for more information on this topic.

Comment: Apparently, it takes a second, if I use document.write instead. I'll look into innerText instead. Thanks.