# My JavaScript code isn't working properly in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser

I have a to-do list application on [my website](http://www.michaelmanhire.com/portfolio/just_do_it.html) that I built using JavaScript. It works perfectly in Google Chrome, but it doesn't work in Mozilla Firefox. I have read that each browser interprets JavaScript differently, but I haven't been able to pinpoint exactly what the problem is in the code.

So, what happens in Firefox is this: When you type something into the text input and click the "Add Task" button, it does show that a task has been added. However, the label appears blank, as do the Edit and Delete buttons. All of the functionality appears to work as normal (the Edit and Delete buttons work properly, they just don't display the text).

In the code, the each list item is created by a function called `createTask`. Its code is:

```
var createTask = function(taskString) {
    // taskString is the value of the text input (whatever the user wants the task to read)

    // Create Elements
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var editInput = document.createElement("input");
    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    // Modify Elements
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    label.innerText = taskString;
    editInput.type = "text";
    editButton.innerText = "Edit";
    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";

    // Add Event Listeners
    checkbox.addEventListener("change", markTask);
    editButton.addEventListener("click", editTask);
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);

    // Append the Elements to the List Item
    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);

    return listItem;
}
```

Then, the function `addTask` appends `listItem` to the unordered list that is the tasks list.

var addTask = function() {

```
    if (addInput.value === "") {
        addError.style.display = "block"; // Display error message if no input
    } else {
        addError.style.display = "none"; // Stop displaying error message
        var listItem = createTask(addInput.value); // Put user input into createTask function
        tasksList.appendChild(listItem); // Add the new list item to the unordered list
        addInput.value = ""; // Reset the text input field to blank
        addInput.focus();
    }
}
```

Looking more closely, within the `createTask` function, there is:

```
    label.innerText = taskString;
    editButton.innerText = "Edit";
    deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
```

So, I thought that the `innerText` property may not work properly in Firefox, but I tried changing it to `innerHTML` and `textContent`, and that doesn't work either!

Any ideas?

Comment: Switching it to `.textContent` fixes it for me. Make sure you change it in all places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

innerText is deprecated. 
Try using textContent instead.

This issue has been described here: 
['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: The OP already said they tried `textContent` and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Yeah, I already tried `textContent`, but that is good to know that `innerText` is deprecated. In the meantime, I'll keep playing around with it.

Comment: @Michael: As I said above, `.textContent` fixes it. If it's not fixing it, then either you missed some places, or the script is cached by your browser so it's still reading the old one.

Answer (score 0):

use `.textContent` and log `listItem` in `console` you will see they are constructed properly.below is your code with small changes.tested in `firefox`:

```
var createTask = function(taskString) {
    // taskString is the value of the text input (whatever the user wants the task to read)
    // Create Elements
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    var editInput = document.createElement("input");
    var editButton = document.createElement("button");
    var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

    // Modify Elements
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    label.textContent = taskString;
    editInput.type = "text";
    editButton.textContent = "Edit";
    deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
//alert(deleteButton.textContent);
    // Add Event Listeners
 // checkbox.addEventListener("change", markTask);  // commented these because i do not had these objects.
   // editButton.addEventListener("click", editTask);
   // deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteTask);

    // Append the Elements to the List Item
    listItem.appendChild(checkbox);
    listItem.appendChild(label);
    listItem.appendChild(editInput);
    listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
    listItem.appendChild(editButton);

console.log(listItem);
    return listItem;
}
```