# jQuery-based HTML parsing in Javascript and Firefox: can't explain behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I'm writing a small script to parse a HTML page with the help of jQuery; while my script works as I expect in Chrome, IE and Safari, I can't explain its behavior in Firefox (version 36.0.1). Here it is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myURL.aspx',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
    html = $.parseHTML(data, document, true);

    $.each(html, function (i, el) {
        if (el.nodeName === "FORM") {
            $.each(el.childNodes, function (j, n) {
                if (typeof n != "undefined") {
                    if (n.nodeName === "SCRIPT") {
                        if (typeof n.innerText != "undefined") {
                            if (n.innerText.indexOf("...") != -1) {
                                if (n.nodeType == 1) {
                                    $("body").append(n);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

});

The problem is, I set a breakpoint on the line where I'm calling `append` and, if I inspect the properties of `n` the first time the debugger breaks, I see that `n.nodeName` is not `SCRIPT`, `n.innerText` is `undefined` and `n.nodeType` is `3`. Is there something I'm completely misunderstanding?

Comment: Firefox appears to support the `innerText` property now, though it came pretty late to the party: ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox). I'm not sure whether that's related to your problem.

Comment: use elm.children instead of elm.childNodes unless you really do want whitespace, comment nodes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Firefox 36.0.1 is not completely ok with property `innerText`, after all (thanks apsillers!). I replaced it with `textContent` and now the script works in Firefox, Chrome, IE and Safari.