# jQuery innerText on firefox -> jQuery(this).text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

EDIT: My problem was not jQuery.each but innerText ; many thanks [Djave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/630203/djave)!

Yet another question about jQuery.each

http://jsfiddle.net/vL4v696a/

```
jQuery("div").each(function(){
  jQuery("p").append("<br/>"+this.id+" "+this.innerText);
});
```

Expected:

```
un solo
deux duo
...
```

Unexpected:

```
un undefined
deux undefined
```

Why does chrome get this.innerText while firefox cannot? Is it a bug?

Seems related to latests firefox versions.

Any alternative? Thanks by advance.

Comment: Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`. [They support the proper usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox).

Comment: Yeah, there are a few inconsistencies between browsers, but also jQuery can help you with this, using things such as `jQuery(this).text()`