# If li class equals to then add hyperlink

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Could someone help me with a javascript that add a hyperlink to a list class? i.e. if class="backTo" then add href="index" to that class.

Current HTML

```
 <div class="secondary-nav">
        <ul class="secondary-nav">            
                <li class="backTo">Campaign</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So the javascript does this:

```
 <div class="secondary-nav">
        <ul class="secondary-nav">            
                <li class="backTo"><a href="index">Campaign</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="top">title 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this at any place below the navigation, or include it in an external script:

```
<script>
    var backListItem = document.querySelector('.backTo');
    backListItem.innerHTML = '<a href="index">'+backListItem.innerHTML+'</a>';
</script>
```

Comment: Use `textContent`, `innerText` won't work in Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: @Pavlo That was in 2009, but if you need to support a really old version of Firefox, you could use `innerHTML` or `textContent` instead of `innerText`.

Comment: Have you even tried it? Try to evaluate `document.body.innerText` in *any* version of Firefox – it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Tried it, I stand corrected :)  will update my answer.