# getElementById returns null in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have an applcation built using Javascript and HTML5. I also have some scripts included that is to be executed on button click.

The application seems to be working fine on chrome but when I tried to run on Firefox it fails. I tried to debug and found out that **document.getElementByID()** returns **null** value. But the element is already existing in the body of the document.

**Info:**
Platform : Firefox 
Version : Mozilla Firefox ESR 
OS : Windows 7 64bit

I did refer to several similar questions on stackoverflow and found that the script part has to be within the **body**. But I am wondering if it is the case, then how could it work on Chrome?

Comment: it would be more helpful if you could create a jsfiddle

Comment: Post the actual code involved.

Comment: We don't need a jsFiddle. Post relevant code in the question and you'll get your answer.

Comment: Could be many reasons, post code. One thing you could be doing is trying to get an element before it's loaded into the DOM. Another is just that you spelled your ID wrong in your HTML/JS. If you post code, myself and many others will assist you.

Comment: Hey Guys,
I have updated the question. 
@EvinUgur The ID is correct. It is working on chrome but not on firefox.

Comment: By the way I would like to ask the down voters to please be kind to let me know "How can this be off the topic?" Thanks

Comment: The code should be posted **here**, as part of the question, and not as a link to some other site.

Comment: @SangameshHs I stepped through your function in FireFox's debugger and the call to getElementById did not return null it returned a valid reference to the appropriate HTML element.

Comment: [See this SO question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox) The problem is not with `.getElementById()`, it's with the use of `.innerText` which is not supported by Firefox.

Comment: @Pointy You are right. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Post code *directly* in  your question. Don't just link to it. You've asked enough questions to know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property .innerText is not supported by Firefox.  I have added the code you were referring to below so others can have a better sense of context on what is being discussed.

```
function UF_FC_OIST() {
    var rd1 = "BUTTON_GROUP_ITEM_3_btn0_acButton";
    if (document.getElementById(rd1)) {
        var valrd1 = document.getElementById(rd1);
        valrd2 = valrd1.innerText; // <-------------- NOT SUPPORTED BY FIREFOX
        if (valrd2 == 'Umsatz-Forecast ohne IST (Budget) generieren') {
            valrd2 = "ZLF_FC_INIT_OHNE_IST";
        }
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
    window.open("url" + valrd2)
};
```

Additional resources on innerText:

http://quirksmode.org/dom/html/#t07

http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Comment: Thanks. That's true like @Pointy mentioned before. Appreciate it.