# Retrieve value of <p> from HTML & convert to number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to retrieve the value (example below is 7) of a paragraph element from my HTML doc, then reference this value in an external javascript file and use it as a variable.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="container">

        <p id="speedTransition">7</p>

    </div>
```

I then populate the js using .innerHTML calls so I can reference the id but...

*Javascript Attempt 1:*

```
var b   = Number(speedTransition);
```

*Javascript Attempt 2:*

```
var b   = document.getElementById("speedTransition").value = Number(speedTransition);
```

All console calls referencing "speedTransition" come back undefined and thus speedTrans returns NaN.

```
console.log("speedTransition = " + container.speedTransition);
console.log("speedTrans = " + speedTrans);
```

Any help massively appreciated! Thanks guys! First post!

:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were missing `textContent`. This will get you the *text* of the `p` elemeant

```js
var p = document.getElementById('speedTransition');
var text = p.textContent;
var number = Number(text);
document.write(number);
```

```html
<div id="container" class="container">

  <p id="speedTransition">7</p>

</div>
```

Comment: innerHTML iwll give him the HTML of the p element - if there is nothing else in there, the text. To get the text regardless, textContent or innerText

Comment: Wow, just casting to number. And I thought you needed `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: You could even do `var number = +text`

Comment: @GolezTrol, are you saying that sarcastically? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @mplungjan, you are right. Thanks for the tip. updated my answer

Comment: Yeah, but add the textContent if no innerText

Comment: @AmmarCSE No, not at all. I think this is nicer, but I didn't know this. I would have done it the way Ajay Chaudhary suggested in his answer.

Comment: @mplungjan, you said 'but add the textContent if no innerText'. Do you mean if the text was hidden then textContent would have a value while innerText doesnt?

Comment: No. innerText is [not supported by all browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox), most of the ones that do not support it, support textContent

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for your awesome and helpful information. Ive learned more than the OP answering this question :). Thats what I love about SO

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys - this works! Tried out textContent too. Perfect!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("speedTransition").innerHTML,10);
```

Comment: How are you going to parse integer from the DOM element?

Comment: And I added the radix in case it contains "08" or "09"

Comment: Thanks Ajay + mplungjan, works a treat - I may well go with this route to keep my code light :)