# Inline JavaScript works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, inline-code

I have a page layout in which I have created HTML table structure. In between, I want to display static text if the `td` is empty. My code is simple:

```
<td> 
    <div id="dvCountry">
        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Country" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue></div>
    <div id="dvOffice">,<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue FieldName="Office" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:FieldValue></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var td = document.getElementById("dvCountry");
            if(td.innerText.length == 0){
                td.innerText = "Group";
                var divOffice = document.getElementById("dvOffice");
                divOffice.innerText = "";
            }

    </script>
</td>
```

The above code is working fine in IE, and Chrome but not working in Firefox.

What am I missing?

Comment: Any errors in the console? How does it not work? What have you tried in the field of debugging?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox

Comment: check your console for errors and also try console.log(td.innerText.length, td.innerText); to check whether or not firefox is getting a text value. (maybe the linebreak/spaces are causing this issue) alternatively check td.textContent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from `innerText`.
See: ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

You should use jQuery or use `innerHTML`.

Comment: In console, no errors are generated after using innerHTML but check if any values is there or not `td.innerHTML` returns `\n\t\t\t\t\t` if no values are there. How can check if the values is there or not in my code.?

Comment: @MohemmadK Maybe can you use [`str.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), in order to remove uninteresing chars? Also, try using [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead.