# HTML - Script working in JSFiddle but not when I run the script alone

Tags: javascript, html, local

The following script works as expected on JSFiddle, but when I copy the script out and put it in a .html file locally it no longer works. The hyperlinks for the Reports no longer appear.

below is the script I'm saving to a .html file, which should be a copy of what's in JSFiddle link above.

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content - Language" content="en - gb">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>Report Menu</title> 
<style fprolloverstyle>A:hover {color: red; font-weight: bold} 
</style> 
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
function getMonthString(num) {

    var month; //Create a local variable to hold the string
    switch (num) {
        case 0:
            month = "01";
            break;
        case 1:
            month = "02";
            break;
        case 2:
            month = "03";
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "04";
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "05";
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "06";
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "07";
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "08";
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "09";
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "10";
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "11";
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "12";
            break;
        default:
            month = "13";
    }
    return month;
};
var d = new Date();
var name = 'Report_';
var name2 = 'Report_';

name += d.getFullYear();
name += getMonthString(d.getMonth());
name += d.getDate() - 1;
name += '.pdf';

name2 += d.getFullYear();
name2 += getMonthString(d.getMonth());
name2 += d.getDate() - 2;
name2 += '.pdf';

document.getElementById('lnk').innerText = name;

document.getElementById('lnk').setAttribute('href', name)

document.getElementById('lnk2').innerText = name2;

document.getElementById('lnk2').setAttribute('href', name2)
}//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
  <title>Report Menu</title>
</head>
<body LEFTMARGIN="150">
    <table height=1 align="Right">
         <Font Size="1"> <font face='Mylius Sans'color= 999999 >This menu last refreshed: 10Aug15 02:19</font> 
    </table>
    <p><font face="Arial" size="3"><B>Daily_Network_Operations_Report</B></p><p><font size="2">Choose your report:</font>

    </p>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5"><font size="2">
<tr><a href='#' id="lnk"></a></tr>
<tr><a href='#' id="lnk2"></a></tr>




</table>
<p><font face="Arial" size="1">earlier reports may be available - please email </p>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: What does this script work??

Comment: @VivekGupta Check the JSFiddle, instead of asking.

Comment: This works fine for me

Comment: @AltayMazlum jsfiddle is showing one static page (I checked in firefox). :(

Comment: As I said it works fine in JSFiddle but when I copy it out into a .html file and save it locally and open it the links no longer appear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

at the start of your  tag (by the way, you are missing the start  tag.

The problem is that it's probably going into compatibility mode for whichever zone you are running it under.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the question have been answered I would like to add something that was pointed out by  Altay Mazlum. This code is not working under Firefox (in my case at least).

You have to replace innerText by textContent.

Response from this thread (['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)) by [Prakash K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159470/prakash-k):

> Firefox uses the [W3C-compliant](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level->3-Core-20040407/core.html#Node3-textContent) [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.textContent) property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your script at end of body tag:

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Oe3n4Z53FlfnTeH8cZv?p=preview)

[Not working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/moGgIpH37OhI2jngseqW?p=preview)

Another solution. Using `onload` at body tag:

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BetpkHEAisQpILY0IkGW?p=preview)

Comment: Try link now @AltayMazlum

Comment: What do you get when you click on the link? I just get some error.

Comment: You are getting because redirection is blocked by `Plunker` it will work in local.

Comment: See this http://plnkr.co/edit/nIf8VFuXqjGbpBeDu3yb?p=preview. Means redirection won't work at plunker. But problem was link not showing.