# Should I be using replace() method?

Tags: javascript

I am a total noob to javascript and need some direction.

I am trying to do the following:

Create 3 text boxes:

- User enters a string in the first text box.
- User enters string to be replaced (part of the first string) in the second text box.
- User enters new string to insert in third text box.

Button – calls a function to perform the replacement and displays the results in all uppercase.

I am using `document.querySelector("myID").value;` to grab the value entered, but i am not sure if i should be using `replace()` for this. Or if the variable needs to be converted to something else. (very confused)

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us our code, so it could be better answered. Better, put it on JsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
<body>
    <textarea id="textArea" ></textarea><br>
    <input id="input1" /><br>
    <input id="input2" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Replace" onclick="doReplace()" />
    <div id="output">OUTPUT!</div>

    <script>
        function doReplace() {
            var getById = document.getElementById.bind(document);
            var get = function(id) { return getById(id).value };
            var text = get('textArea'),
                input1 = get('input1'),
                input2 = get('input2'),
                div = getById('output');

            var regex = new RegExp(input1, "g"); // to replace globally you need this!
            div.innerHTML = text.replace(regex, input2).toUpperCase();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/34c2gugt/)

Comment: You should add a jsfiddle or a snippet to demonstrate your code.

Comment: @Daniel Cheung: thank you for your comment. the jsfiddle link added.

Comment: There **is** no `innerText` property, but there is a `innerHTML`. Did you even tested it? :/

Comment: hmmm, HTMLElement has innerText property as well as innerHTML.
and yes i tested the jsfiddle in google chrome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox InnerText doesn't seem to be a W3C standard

Comment: you are right. the code doesn't work in firefox. you could use textContent or innerHTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript by default recognizes everything as string, when given a string operation. In this case you could use `replace()` method directly without any conversions.