# Firefox shows [object HTMLDivElement] instead of value of JS calculation

Tags: javascript, object, dom

The following script should calculate an amount of money which was saved. 
in every type of browser its working (IE,Chrome,Opera) but not FF. 
It shows me [object HTMLDivElement] instead of the value which was calculated.

```
  var betragsec = ({input:loszahlen}*.25)/31536000;
    var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    var now = new Date();
    var start = new Date("Januar 01, 2015, 00:00:00");
    var diff = (now - start)/1000;
    var current =(diff*betragsec);
    update();
    function update() {
        amount.innerText = formatMoney(current);
    }
    setInterval(function(){
        current += betragsec;
        update();
        },1000);
    function formatMoney(amount) {
        var euros = Math.floor(amount).toString().split('');
        var cents = (Math.round((amount%1)*100)/100).toString().split('.')[1];
        if(typeof cents == 'undefined'){
            cents = '00';
        }else if(cents.length == 1){
            cents = cents + '0';
        }
        var str = '';
        for(i=euros.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            str += euros.splice(0,1);
            if(i%3 == 0 && i != 0) str += '.';
        }
        return  str + ',' + cents + ' ' + '\u20AC';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because FF use the `.textContent` property, which is W3C complient.

You can use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to get this code work cross browser

```
amount.textContent = formatMoney(current);
// OR
amount.innerHTML = formatMoney(current);
```

Duplicate of this question can be
 :
['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)