# Firefox ONLY wont run one line of javascript code in an if statement but does run the other lines - chrome and safari run all lines of code

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have one line of javascript code that ***firefox only*** wont run. I have searched through stackoverflow, mozilla etc...all point to javascript being enabled but it is enabled and all script except one line wont run. It is within an if statement - one statement executes in the 'if' statement and the other doesnt. No answers anywhere on topic

this is my code:

```
/*figuring out how to fill in cell values using js*/

//need to set i counter according to which day is the 1st of the month

var i; //loop counter - correlates to <td> array

switch(firstId) {
    case 1 :
        i = 0;
        break;
    case 2 :
        i = 1;
        break;
    case 3 :
        i = 2;
        break;
    case 4 :
        i = 3;
        break;
    case 5 :
        i = 4;
        break;
    case 6 :
        i = 5;
        break;
    case 7 :
        i = 6;
        break;
}

var add = i;
var subt = i - 1;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("jan");
for(i; i < count + add; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "#dadfe7";
    x[i].innerText = (i - subt);
}
```

Firefox wont run this line
`x[i].innerText = (i - subt);`
the last line in the `if` statement 
but Chrome and Safari do. 
No errors are thrown that I can see in chrome or firefox inspectors.

I would greatly appreciate any help. You can see the results by going to 
http://sunsetprayers.com/

It is a 2016 Calendar - I am learning javascript and want to have the months load in the correct squares using javascript code.

Any help is greatly appreciated!! ~jeanie

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['innerText' works in IE, but not in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359469/innertext-works-in-ie-but-not-in-firefox)

Comment: Why would you use that switch statement instead of just a single `if` statement that subtracts 1 from `firstId` and assigns it to `i`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`innerText` is an invention of Internet Explorer, that maybe Chrome adapts to it. But is not an standard. To write the standard use `textContent`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

`x[i].textContent = (i - subt);`

In the documentation you can find the differences between `textContent` and `innerText` and `innerHTML`

Note that you said:

> I have searched through stackoverflow, mozilla etc...all point to javascript being enabled but it is enabled and all script except one line wont run.

But that's not true, I spent 10 seconds to find the MDN documentation about that.

Comment: Thank you, Marcos!! That fixed it. And I am going to read that entire documentation you found in 10 seconds!!! I wish I had found that. Being pretty new to javascript I am not 100% the right terms to find the answers I need. But I will 100% read all of this you shared. Super grateful for your time!!!

Comment: You're welcome, don't worry. Make a good search saves you a lot of time!! Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you!! and to you too.. in all you do :-)