# Getting text inside p element inside div

Tags: protractor

I have following rendered html

```
<div class="footer text-center">
  <p>By signing up, you agree to abc's <b>Terms of Service</b>, <b>Cookie Policy</b>, <b>Privacy Policy and Content Policies.</b></p>
</div>
```

I am trying following to validate text is appearing as expected.
But getAttribute('value') returns Null and hence test failing.

```
element(by.tagName('p')).getAttribute('value').then(function (text) {
    expect(text).toBe("By signing up, you agree to abc's Terms of Service, Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy and Content Policies.");
});
```

Comment: you want [getText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText).  I would suggest you become familiar with the protractor API, plenty to learn on there.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the **innerHtml** property.
Check this:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use getText. It will return you all text from inner tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

As you try to `getText()` as nicely formatted string, you should indeed use [`getText()` as described in Protractor API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText). It will remove the `<b>`-tags and will also i.e. remove double-spaces.

Further because `getText()` returns a promise and because `expect()` will then resolve the promise, there is no need to use `then()` in your case.

**Overall here is how your code should look like:**

```
expect(element(by.tagName('p')).getText()).toBe("By signing up, you agree to abc's Terms of Service, Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy and Content Policies.");
```

Now some more valuable infos:

- [about the differences between `getAttribute('value')` and `getText()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359822/8683679)
- [about `innerText` vs `textContent`](http://clubajax.org/plain-text-vs-innertext-vs-textcontent/)